# Jq Grid - Show/Hide all Grid

Tags: jqgrid-formatter

I have four jqgrid in my jsp application. They are loaded via ajax using the method addXmlData (messageXML) How can I hide three of the grid and show only one of them, and in accordance with the click of a button, hide and show the other grids. The content of the grids are updated according to the user's needs via ajax. I need only show one at a time not to mess up the form.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the solution. Pretty simple to tell the truth. just add the tags table between divs and use the $ ("# divid"). hide (); to hide and $ ("# divid"). show (); to display.

The code was as follows.

```
...

    <div id="divid">
        <table id="listid" class="scroll"> <tr> <td/> </ tr> </ table>
    </ div>

...

<script>
...
    $ ("#divid"). hide ();
    $ ("#divid"). show ();
...
</ script>
```